# Can I create two threads and run them in a task in c#?

Tags: c#, multithreading, task

I have to create several tasks in c# which execute graph traversal function, now what I want to do is to have two independent threads which takes different sources as a parameter to that traversal function and started in a task itself. I have a thought of using task because I want  4 task to work in a parallel manner but make them use two threads  which executes same function? Is that possible?

So what I want is ,`task1` contains `thread1` , `thread2` &  `task2` contains `thread3`, `thread4` & `task3` contains `thread5`, `thread6`.

All all of these threads executes same function. Is it possible to implement? Is there any other way?

Comment: Why shouldn't it be possible?

Comment: Just try it and you see if it's possible.

Comment: see i tried it by giving task 1 function which creates two threads. and these two threads executes graph traversal function. now threads did not execute that function. so now i think what i did is wrong. @Nolonar

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare a class that you can use to pass parameters to the threads:

> ```
> class ThreadParamsClass
> {
>     internal int int1, int2;
>
>     internal ThreadParamsClass(int int1, int int2)
>     {
>         this.int1 = int1;
>         this.int2 = int2;
>     }
> }
> ```

1. Create several instances of the class and start the threads, passing the parameter object to the thread:

> ```
> ThreadParamsClass[] ThreadParams = new ThreadParamsClass[6];
> ThreadParams[0] = new ThreadParamsClass(1, 2);
> ThreadParams[1] = new ThreadParamsClass(3, 4);
> ThreadParams[2] = new ThreadParamsClass(5, 6);
> ThreadParams[3] = new ThreadParamsClass(7, 8);
> ThreadParams[4] = new ThreadParamsClass(9, 10);
> ThreadParams[5] = new ThreadParamsClass(11, 12);
> for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
> {
>     Thread Thread1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(Function1));
>     Thread1.Start(ThreadParams[i]);
> }
>
> void Function1(object Params)
> {
>     ThreadParamsClass ThreadParams = (ThreadParamsClass)Params;
>     int result = ThreadParams.int1 + ThreadParams.int2;
> }
> ```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but this is not what i want to do. i 4 want tasks to create two threads each , and execute same graph traversal function. help me !!